# Interactive spider or radar chart using d3

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, radar-chart

I'm looking for a spider chart/radar chart for HTML/javascript that is also interactive. I would like the user to move all the endpoints and store the end result.

I have been searching for a while and although I have found some nice chart components all of them where static and could only updated using code.

Comment: I do not know of anything which provides it out of the box. However, as it stands, this is not a good question for SO. I would recommend that you try to write your own solution and post more specific questions if you run into any particular problems. Also, welcome to SO! :)

Comment: I was hoping that some experts on stackoverflow might know some projects that I couldn't find. If not, I have to give it a try myself

Comment: Unfortunately, SO is not a good place for such repositories of lists. These lists generally tend to become opinionated and link rot.

Answer (score 7):

An **Interactive D3 Radar chart** example:

[image]

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"/>
  <title>Radar chart</title>
    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="RadarChart.js"></script>
    <style>
        body {
          overflow: hidden;
          margin: 0;
          font-size: 14px;
          font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica;
        }

        #chart {
          position: absolute;
          top: 50px;
          left: 100px;
        }   
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="body">
      <div id="chart"></div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

**RadarChart.js**

```
var RadarChart = {
  draw: function(id, d, options){
  var cfg = {
     radius: 5,
     w: 600,
     h: 600,
     factor: 1,
     factorLegend: .85,
     levels: 3,
     maxValue: 0,
     radians: 2 * Math.PI,
     opacityArea: 0.5,
     ToRight: 5,
     TranslateX: 80,
     TranslateY: 30,
     ExtraWidthX: 100,
     ExtraWidthY: 100,
     color: d3.scale.category10()
    };

    if('undefined' !== typeof options){
      for(var i in options){
        if('undefined' !== typeof options[i]){
          cfg[i] = options[i];
        }
      }
    }
    cfg.maxValue = Math.max(cfg.maxValue, d3.max(d, function(i){return d3.max(i.map(function(o){return o.value;}))}));
    var allAxis = (d[0].map(function(i, j){return i.axis}));
    var total = allAxis.length;
    var radius = cfg.factor*Math.min(cfg.w/2, cfg.h/2);
    var Format = d3.format('%');
    d3.select(id).select("svg").remove();

    var g = d3.select(id)
            .append("svg")
            .attr("width", cfg.w+cfg.ExtraWidthX)
            .attr("height", cfg.h+cfg.ExtraWidthY)
            .append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + cfg.TranslateX + "," + cfg.TranslateY + ")");
            ;

    var tooltip;

    //Circular segments
    for(var j=0; j<cfg.levels-1; j++){
      var levelFactor = cfg.factor*radius*((j+1)/cfg.levels);
      g.selectAll(".levels")
       .data(allAxis)
       .enter()
       .append("svg:line")
       .attr("x1", function(d, i){return levelFactor*(1-cfg.factor*Math.sin(i*cfg.radians/total));})
       .attr("y1", function(d, i){return levelFactor*(1-cfg.factor*Math.cos(i*cfg.radians/total));})
       .attr("x2", function(d, i){return levelFactor*(1-cfg.factor*Math.sin((i+1)*cfg.radians/total));})
       .attr("y2", function(d, i){return levelFactor*(1-cfg.factor*Math.cos((i+1)*cfg.radians/total));})
       .attr("class", "line")
       .style("stroke", "grey")
       .style("stroke-opacity", "0.75")
       .style("stroke-width", "0.3px")
       .attr("transform", "translate(" + (cfg.w/2-levelFactor) + ", " + (cfg.h/2-levelFactor) + ")");
    }

    //Text indicating at what % each level is
    for(var j=0; j<cfg.levels; j++){
      var levelFactor = cfg.factor*radius*((j+1)/cfg.levels);
      g.selectAll(".levels")
       .data([1]) //dummy data
       .enter()
       .append("svg:text")
       .attr("x", function(d){return levelFactor*(1-cfg.factor*Math.sin(0));})
       .attr("y", function(d){return levelFactor*(1-cfg.factor*Math.cos(0));})
       .attr("class", "legend")
       .style("font-family", "sans-serif")
       .style("font-size", "10px")
       .attr("transform", "translate(" + (cfg.w/2-levelFactor + cfg.ToRight) + ", " + (cfg.h/2-levelFactor) + ")")
       .attr("fill", "#737373")
       .text(Format((j+1)*cfg.maxValue/cfg.levels));
    }

    series = 0;

    var axis = g.selectAll(".axis")
            .data(allAxis)
            .enter()
            .append("g")
            .attr("class", "axis");

    axis.append("line")
        .attr("x1", cfg.w/2)
        .attr("y1", cfg.h/2)
        .attr("x2", function(d, i){return cfg.w/2*(1-cfg.factor*Math.sin(i*cfg.radians/total));})
        .attr("y2", function(d, i){return cfg.h/2*(1-cfg.factor*Math.cos(i*cfg.radians/total));})
        .attr("class", "line")
        .style("stroke", "grey")
        .style("stroke-width", "1px");

    axis.append("text")
        .attr("class", "legend")
        .text(function(d){return d})
        .style("font-family", "sans-serif")
        .style("font-size", "11px")
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
        .attr("dy", "1.5em")
        .attr("transform", function(d, i){return "translate(0, -10)"})
        .attr("x", function(d, i){return cfg.w/2*(1-cfg.factorLegend*Math.sin(i*cfg.radians/total))-60*Math.sin(i*cfg.radians/total);})
        .attr("y", function(d, i){return cfg.h/2*(1-Math.cos(i*cfg.radians/total))-20*Math.cos(i*cfg.radians/total);});


    d.forEach(function(y, x){
      dataValues = [];
      g.selectAll(".nodes")
        .data(y, function(j, i){
          dataValues.push([
            cfg.w/2*(1-(parseFloat(Math.max(j.value, 0))/cfg.maxValue)*cfg.factor*Math.sin(i*cfg.radians/total)), 
            cfg.h/2*(1-(parseFloat(Math.max(j.value, 0))/cfg.maxValue)*cfg.factor*Math.cos(i*cfg.radians/total))
          ]);
        });
      dataValues.push(dataValues[0]);
      g.selectAll(".area")
                     .data([dataValues])
                     .enter()
                     .append("polygon")
                     .attr("class", "radar-chart-serie"+series)
                     .style("stroke-width", "2px")
                     .style("stroke", cfg.color(series))
                     .attr("points",function(d) {
                         var str="";
                         for(var pti=0;pti<d.length;pti++){
                             str=str+d[pti][0]+","+d[pti][2]+" ";
                         }
                         return str;
                      })
                     .style("fill", function(j, i){return cfg.color(series)})
                     .style("fill-opacity", cfg.opacityArea)
                     .on('mouseover', function (d){
                                        z = "polygon."+d3.select(this).attr("class");
                                        g.selectAll("polygon")
                                         .transition(200)
                                         .style("fill-opacity", 0.1); 
                                        g.selectAll(z)
                                         .transition(200)
                                         .style("fill-opacity", .7);
                                      })
                     .on('mouseout', function(){
                                        g.selectAll("polygon")
                                         .transition(200)
                                         .style("fill-opacity", cfg.opacityArea);
                     });
      series++;
    });
    series=0;


    d.forEach(function(y, x){
      g.selectAll(".nodes")
        .data(y).enter()
        .append("svg:circle")
        .attr("class", "radar-chart-serie"+series)
        .attr('r', cfg.radius)
        .attr("alt", function(j){return Math.max(j.value, 0)})
        .attr("cx", function(j, i){
          dataValues.push([
            cfg.w/2*(1-(parseFloat(Math.max(j.value, 0))/cfg.maxValue)*cfg.factor*Math.sin(i*cfg.radians/total)), 
            cfg.h/2*(1-(parseFloat(Math.max(j.value, 0))/cfg.maxValue)*cfg.factor*Math.cos(i*cfg.radians/total))
        ]);
        return cfg.w/2*(1-(Math.max(j.value, 0)/cfg.maxValue)*cfg.factor*Math.sin(i*cfg.radians/total));
        })
        .attr("cy", function(j, i){
          return cfg.h/2*(1-(Math.max(j.value, 0)/cfg.maxValue)*cfg.factor*Math.cos(i*cfg.radians/total));
        })
        .attr("data-id", function(j){return j.axis})
        .style("fill", cfg.color(series)).style("fill-opacity", .9)
        .on('mouseover', function (d){
                    newX =  parseFloat(d3.select(this).attr('cx')) - 10;
                    newY =  parseFloat(d3.select(this).attr('cy')) - 5;

                    tooltip
                        .attr('x', newX)
                        .attr('y', newY)
                        .text(Format(d.value))
                        .transition(200)
                        .style('opacity', 1);

                    z = "polygon."+d3.select(this).attr("class");
                    g.selectAll("polygon")
                        .transition(200)
                        .style("fill-opacity", 0.1); 
                    g.selectAll(z)
                        .transition(200)
                        .style("fill-opacity", .7);
                  })
        .on('mouseout', function(){
                    tooltip
                        .transition(200)
                        .style('opacity', 0);
                    g.selectAll("polygon")
                        .transition(200)
                        .style("fill-opacity", cfg.opacityArea);
                  })
        .append("svg:title")
        .text(function(j){return Math.max(j.value, 0)});

      series++;
    });
    //Tooltip
    tooltip = g.append('text')
               .style('opacity', 0)
               .style('font-family', 'sans-serif')
               .style('font-size', '13px');
  }
};
```

**Script.js**

```
var w = 500,
    h = 500;

var colorscale = d3.scale.category10();

//Legend titles
var LegendOptions = ['Smartphone','Tablet'];

//Data
var d = [
          [
            {axis:"Email",value:0.59},
            {axis:"Social Networks",value:0.56},
            {axis:"Internet Banking",value:0.42},
            {axis:"News Sportsites",value:0.34},
            {axis:"Search Engine",value:0.48},
            {axis:"View Shopping sites",value:0.14},
            {axis:"Paying Online",value:0.11},
            {axis:"Buy Online",value:0.05},
            {axis:"Stream Music",value:0.07},
            {axis:"Online Gaming",value:0.12},
            {axis:"Navigation",value:0.27},
            {axis:"App connected to TV program",value:0.03},
            {axis:"Offline Gaming",value:0.12},
            {axis:"Photo Video",value:0.4},
            {axis:"Reading",value:0.03},
            {axis:"Listen Music",value:0.22},
            {axis:"Watch TV",value:0.03},
            {axis:"TV Movies Streaming",value:0.03},
            {axis:"Listen Radio",value:0.07},
            {axis:"Sending Money",value:0.18},
            {axis:"Other",value:0.07},
            {axis:"Use less Once week",value:0.08}
          ],[
            {axis:"Email",value:0.48},
            {axis:"Social Networks",value:0.41},
            {axis:"Internet Banking",value:0.27},
            {axis:"News Sportsites",value:0.28},
            {axis:"Search Engine",value:0.46},
            {axis:"View Shopping sites",value:0.29},
            {axis:"Paying Online",value:0.11},
            {axis:"Buy Online",value:0.14},
            {axis:"Stream Music",value:0.05},
            {axis:"Online Gaming",value:0.19},
            {axis:"Navigation",value:0.14},
            {axis:"App connected to TV program",value:0.06},
            {axis:"Offline Gaming",value:0.24},
            {axis:"Photo Video",value:0.17},
            {axis:"Reading",value:0.15},
            {axis:"Listen Music",value:0.12},
            {axis:"Watch TV",value:0.1},
            {axis:"TV Movies Streaming",value:0.14},
            {axis:"Listen Radio",value:0.06},
            {axis:"Sending Money",value:0.16},
            {axis:"Other",value:0.07},
            {axis:"Use less Once week",value:0.17}
          ]
        ];

//Options for the Radar chart, other than default
var mycfg = {
  w: w,
  h: h,
  maxValue: 0.6,
  levels: 6,
  ExtraWidthX: 300
}

//Call function to draw the Radar chart
//Will expect that data is in %'s
RadarChart.draw("#chart", d, mycfg);

////////////////////////////////////////////
/////////// Initiate legend ////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////

var svg = d3.select('#body')
    .selectAll('svg')
    .append('svg')
    .attr("width", w+300)
    .attr("height", h)

//Create the title for the legend
var text = svg.append("text")
    .attr("class", "title")
    .attr('transform', 'translate(90,0)') 
    .attr("x", w - 70)
    .attr("y", 10)
    .attr("font-size", "12px")
    .attr("fill", "#404040")
    .text("What % of owners use a specific service in a week");

//Initiate Legend   
var legend = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "legend")
    .attr("height", 100)
    .attr("width", 200)
    .attr('transform', 'translate(90,20)') 
    ;
    //Create colour squares
    legend.selectAll('rect')
      .data(LegendOptions)
      .enter()
      .append("rect")
      .attr("x", w - 65)
      .attr("y", function(d, i){ return i * 20;})
      .attr("width", 10)
      .attr("height", 10)
      .style("fill", function(d, i){ return colorscale(i);})
      ;
    //Create text next to squares
    legend.selectAll('text')
      .data(LegendOptions)
      .enter()
      .append("text")
      .attr("x", w - 52)
      .attr("y", function(d, i){ return i * 20 + 9;})
      .attr("font-size", "11px")
      .attr("fill", "#737373")
      .text(function(d) { return d; })
      ;
```

Live Example: http://bl.ocks.org/nbremer/6506614

Comment: Is there an easy way to support that the user is able to move the points?

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at [this](https://github.com/alangrafu/radar-chart-d3).

This is what can be achieved with this alangrafu's code:

[image]

The example is really not interactive in the sense that you described, but it is interactive in other ways, and nothing stops you to implement the interactivity you desire, having the code from example as a good starting point.

Answer (score 4):

Still looking? Check out this project on github, I think that is exactly what you are looking for:

https://github.com/jmstriegel/jquery.spidergraph

Demo: http://www.jqueryrain.com/?jhRGLHlE

I have been looking for such a library on my own for a long time and came across your post. Did you find another solution as well?

Comment: This is the only answer that is truly interactive, in the sense of moving points, but it is only spidergraph. Is there one for radarchart?

Comment: FYI link is no longer valid for demo and is spam